# Как вывести информацию сразу с из двух таблиц, в которых пересекаются только ID клиента?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть две таблицы, одна - покупки клиентов, другая - ремонты клиентов. В них пересекаются только ID клиентов. И я хочу вывести из них информацию в карту каждого клиента. Используя

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM clients c 
LEFT JOIN sale s ON s.card_id = c.card_id  
LEFT JOIN action a ON a.card_id = c.card_id 
WHERE c.card_id = '$search'
```

Я рассчитывал получить таблицу где в одной строке будет покупка  клиента в другой продажа или наоборот или только продажи если клиент только покупал и не ремонтировался.

Однако я получаю смешанную таблицу, т.е. в строке сразу информация и о покупке и о продаже. И к примеру у клиента 2 покупке и 1 ремонт, а в таблице 2 покупке и в каждой фигурирует этот ремонт.

Подскажите что нужно исправить в коде, чтобы получить желаемое.

Исходный данные в таблице покупок

```
id 
card_id
name
phone
date
cost
base
```

И в каждой строке

```
200:44:Карина:8917..:10.01.20:1000:наращивание
201:42:Валя:8927...:11.01.20:500: снятие
```

Исходный данные в таблице ремонта

```
Полные тексты   
id
sale_id
code
quantity
name
cost
sum
date
card_id
```

```
1:1:артикул 556:5 шт:Лак:500:20.10.20.:42
2:2:артикул 345:3 шт:Пудра:1000:21.10.20.:48
```

В итоговой таблице

```
Процедура:Комментарий:Стоимость:Кол-во:ID:Дата.
Покупка:Лак:500:5шт:42:20.10.20
Ремонт:Наращивание:1000:1:42:10.01.20
```

Comment: Покажите пример исходных данных для каждой из трёх таблиц (2-3 строки) и желаемый результат запроса для ЭТИХ данных.

Comment: Если верно понял

Comment: Вообще можно из двух таблиц покупок и ремонтов. В покупках id, карта клиента, купленный товар, стоимость его, дата. В ремонтах id, карта клиента, сделанный ремонт, стоимость его, дата. И нужно чтобы запрос по определенной карте клиента вывел, в хронологическом порядке покупки и ремонты выбранного клиента.

Comment: Т.е. вывел суть операции, потом конкретно какой товар или какой ремонт, стоимость и дату выполнения.

Comment: Я просил примеры исходных данных и результата. Как форматированные таблицы. А от лишних слов толку ноль.

Comment: Ну а как исходные данные? ID:201;Card_id :65;NAME: Валя;BASE: Наращивание ресниц; COST: 1000; DATA:25.07.20///ID:65;Card_id:65; NAME:Валя;PRODUCT:ЛАК;COST:1500;DATA:28.09.20////ID:235;Card_id :65;NAME: Валя;BASE: Снятие лака; COST: 200;DATA:22.10.20

Comment: как то так, если я верно понял

Comment: Пожалуйста, в текст вопроса, форматированным текстом. В комментариях ничего не разобрать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отнеситесь ответственно к публикации примера данных. 1) В таблице ремонта не совпадает количество полей с количеством значений; 2) Итог не соответствует исходным данным.

Comment: Спасибо. Я в целом разобрался. Только должен быть способ, сделать так чтобы в итоговой таблице в строке продажи в столбце товар/процедура можно было указать несколько названий товаров, стоимость каждого и сумму по каждому, в строке процедура в этом же столбце указать к примеру ссылку на карточку процедуры с подробными данными. Почему то это не получается. Может быть как то через IF?

Answer (score 2):

Схематично:

```
SELECT *
FROM clients 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT card_id, 'Продажа' type, sale_date  , sale_amount, sale_price
            FROM sale
          UNION ALL
            SELECT card_id, 'Ремонт'      , action_date, NULL       , action_price
            FROM action ) total USING (card_id)
```

Конкретный текст запроса зависит от желаемого вида вывода и соответствия выходных полей таблиц.

Comment: ну и зачем здесь данные из таблицы клиент, дублированные для каждой записи? зачем вообще извращаться с  юнион если все равно по факту таблицы разные? Шоб було? Зачем вообще тогда люди здесь? Такой ответ может и ИИ дать

Comment: @Ипатьев *ну и зачем здесь данные из таблицы клиент, дублированные для каждой записи?* Для того, чтобы знать, в какую карту класть данные. И скорее всего из таблицы клиентов только номер карты и будет взят, а не все поля - но для более конкретного ответа данных явно недостаточно..

Comment: Но с другой стороны да, если убрать клиента то юнион с вручную отобранными полями пожалуй имеет смысл

Comment: только ему  для одного клиента нужен вывод, а здесь для всех

Comment: @Ипатьев Без таблицы клиентов не обойтись - в остальных таблицах для некоторых может не быть записей. И такие карты не попадут в итоговый отчёт. Ну а отобрать для одного клиента не проблема- просто дополнительные WHERE.

Comment: да не нужен ему никакой отчет. у него карточка клиента. одного

Comment: @Ипатьев Он говорит *"хочу вывести из них информацию в карту **каждого** клиента."* И я понятия не имею, почему в запросе - одна карта. Может, потому, что он просто не смог получить одним массивом для всех сразу.

Comment: Карточка одного клиента, имелл в иду просто, что в карточке каждого клиента чтоб была своя инфа, но это видимо и так понятно

Comment: Спасибо за направление

Comment: @Egomaniac Можно делать запрос для каждой отдельной карты. Можно одним запросом получить все, и уже на клиенте раскидывать. Второе серверу понравится гораздо больше.

Comment: Точно для каждой отдельной карты

Comment: @Egomaniac Тогда таблица клиентов и не нужна - просто UNION двух таблиц.

Comment: Ну я кажется понял, изучу UNION. Спасибо. Если можете еще пример написать, буду признателен.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы получить данные из двух не связанных таблиц в базе данных, надо выполнить два запроса.

Comment: Это ошибочное утверждение.

Comment: о господи, опять набежали чебурашки из очереди проверок